# C Code going straight to "else" statements...

Tags: c

I'm having an issue with my C code. The problem being that it isn't recognizing valid input inside a do...while loop.

```
int stp;

do {

    printf("\nPlease enter the packet data (maximum of 50 numbers): ");
    while(getchar()!='\n');

    scanf("%s", dataTest);

    if(dataTest == '\n')
        scanf("%s", dataTest);

    if(dataTest==1) {

        length = strlen(dataTest); 

        if(length < 50) {

            for(i=0;i<=length && stp!=1;i++) {

                if ( (dataTest[i] >= '0' && dataTest[i] <= '9') || (dataTest[i] == 0) ) { 

                    valid=1;
                    win_linux();

                } else {

                    printf("\nData must contain only numbers, '%c' is not a number. Please try again. \n", dataTest[i]);
                    stp=1;
                    valid=0; 

                }

            }

        } else { 

            valid = 0; 
            while(getchar()!='\n');
            printf("\nData should have no more than 50 numbers, you have entered %i",length); 

        }

    } else { 

        printf("\nNot valid data, numeric only. Please try again"); 
        while(getchar()!='\n');
        valid=0; 

    }

} while(valid!=1);
```

Note that dataTest is an array of 50 `char`s.

For example if I enter 1 (valid input) for the scan f it goes straight to the else statement "Not valid data, numeric only. Please try again"

Any ideas?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: What type is dataTest? First you try to store a string in it (implying char *), then you try to compare it to a character (implying char, which would break scanf), then you try and compare it to 1, which is an int.

Comment: dataTest is a char. The "if(dataTest==1)" condition is supposed to be testing is all input is numeric. any ideas how I could do that within the if statement?

Comment: Wait, I've been reading your other comments. Are you SURE dataType is of type char and not char *?

Comment: dataTest is declared as ... "char dataTest[50];"

Answer (score 1):

`if(dataTest==1)` will never be true, because you are doing `scanf("%s",...)`. `dataTest` is a string, not numeric 1. If you enter `1`, it will be a string (`"1"`), not a number (`1`).

**Edit to address comments:** @Charlieabee: You say, "When I enter any number over one digit it brings up the error saying 'numeric data only.'" Right, because for any number over 1 digit, it is not exactly equal to "1". Your code doesn't test whether `dataTest` is numeric; it tests whether it is *exactly* equal to "1". To test whether every character is a number, you need to loop over the entire string and verify that each character is between "0" and "9".

A much simpler way to do what you are trying to do is `scanf("%d", &intvar)`, where `intvar` is of type `int`. Then, you wouldn't have to worry about string validation at all.

But you say you are trying to receive an array of 50 characters. In that case, you have no choice but to do either `scanf("%d %d %d %d ...", &intvar1, $intvar2, ... &intvar50);` (actually typing out all 50 `%d`s and `$intvarX`s) or do some string parsing. But as it is, your code is doomed, because you compare the *entire* input to the string `"1"`.

Comment: so what would I need to change that to, to ensure that the input is fully numeric?

Comment: Try `if(atoi(dataTest)==1)`

Comment: Care to elaborate? What happens if you do a `printf("%d", dataTest)` or `printf("%s", dataTest)`?

Comment: When I enter any number over one digit it brings up the error saying "numeric data only"

Comment: Also when I do printf("%d" dataTest)... the variable displays as a completely different number. and when I do "%s" the variable displays as expected, but still doesnt validate

Comment: @Charlieabee, please see my edit above. Your test fails because you are not asking, "Is `dataTest` numeric?" You are asking, "Is `dataTest` identical to the string `"1"`?"

Comment: I feel like what he's asking is closer to "is the address of the location the pointer dataTest points to equal to one", since dataTest is a char [50].

Comment: Fixed it guys. Thanks for your help! Solution is below.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (dataTest==1) {
```

is asking "is the string dataTest at the address 1?", and since it's not, it will fail. What you probably want to know is whether or not the string represents the number 1. There are a couple if ways to do that:

```
if (0 == strcmp("1", dataTest)) {
. . .
```

or

```
if (1 == strtol(dataTest, NULL, 10)) {
. . .
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do with if(dataTest==1) is check that the input is all numeric. Not that dataTest represents one.

Comment: That test would not verify that the input is numeric; it would verify that it is exactly 1.

Comment: C has no built-in functions for testing a that whole string is numeric. You have to call `isdigit()` on all of its characters.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I changed

```
if(dataTest == 1) {
```

to

```
if(dataTest >= 0) {
```

This made the program flow correctly. Thanks for your help everybody.

Comment: dataTest will ALWAYS be >= 0. It's a pointer to an array of chars on the stack, the only possible values are 0 (aka NULL) or a valid numeric address which is an unsigned integer greater than zero. And, in fact, since it's on the stack, it will never actually be NULL.

Comment: Sorry if that description is too technical. What you're asserting is accidentally tickling some of the low-level idiosyncracies of C. Either way, if that makes your program work correctly, the solution would be to get rid of that if statement and its associated else. The code will be equivalent to the code with (if dataTest >= 0)

Answer (score 0):

Given the data that's appeared in various comments and answers, I believe I can offer a reasonably thorough diagnosis of the problem.

Since dataTest is a `char [50]` (and thus a `char*`), the assertion `if(dataTest == 1)` is asking if the exact address of memory that dataTest points to is 1. The fact that this sometimes seems to work is incidental. The proposed fix from the asker of changing it to `if(dataTest >= 0)` is telling. On *most* architectures, pointers are always >= 0, with 0 being equivalent to `NULL`. Thus, the OP's fix is effectively removing the if statement and its associated else.

Thus, the solution becomes

```
int stp;

do {

    printf("\nPlease enter the packet data (maximum of 50 numbers): ");
    while(getchar()!='\n');

    scanf("%s", dataTest);

    if(dataTest == '\n')
        scanf("%s", dataTest);

    length = strlen(dataTest); 

    if(length < 50) {

        for(i=0;i<=length && stp!=1;i++) {

            if ( (dataTest[i] >= '0' && dataTest[i] <= '9') || (dataTest[i] == 0) ) { 

                valid=1;
                win_linux();

            } else {

                printf("\nData must contain only numbers, '%c' is not a number. Please try again. \n", dataTest[i]);
                stp=1;
                valid=0; 

            }

        }

    } else { 

        valid = 0; 
        while(getchar()!='\n');
        printf("\nData should have no more than 50 numbers, you have entered %i",length); 

    }

} while(valid!=1);
```

However, it should be noted that this pointer comparison also invalidates a few other lines, such as `if(dataTest == '\n')`, which checks if the address `dataTest` points to happens to be exactly equal to the numeric value of the newline character (almost certainly false). So this line may be removed too.

There are also a few subtle bugs. For instance, scanf will overflow dataTest and corrupt memory if 50 or more characters are entered.

The rest of the asker's code is valid C I/O, albeit a little unclean. The stated changes should make it work as intended, but I would suggest cleaning it up. I offer the following C program which should more or less do what the OP wants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main( void ) {

    // Needs to be size 51 to allow for 50 chars
    char dataTest[51];

    int valid = 0;
    do {
        while(getchar()!='\n'); // Flush stdin
        printf("Please enter the packet data (max of 50 numbers): ");

        // Scanf returns the number of arguments filled
        // %50s says we want to read UP TO 50 chars before we hit whitespace
        int successful = scanf("%50s", dataTest);
        if(!successful) {
                valid = 0;
                continue; // If we didn't read right, try again
        }

        int length = strlen(dataTest);
        if(length == 0) {
               valid = 0;
               continue; // If we only had whitespace, assume invalid
        }

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(dataTest[i] >= '0' && dataTest[i] <= '9' ) {
                valid = 1;
                win_linux(); // this was in the original code by the OP
            } else {
                valid = 0;
                break; // Takes the place of the stp variable
            }
        }
    } while(!valid);

    printf("%s\n", dataTest);
}
```